# How do I get auto-width-columns in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

How do I get auto width in Bootstrap 4 columns?

I need 2 column in a row without fixed width, is it possible?

Comment: Read the docs? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use `col` class. You can use `col-*` also eg: `col-md`

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col">Col1</div>
        <div class="col">Col2</div>
    </div>
```

If you use `col` class the columns will be of equal width.
If you use `col-auto` the width of the column will be the width of the contents in the column.

You can even use a combination of both, like below. In this case the first column width will be equal to the contents of that column. Second column width take the rest of width.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto">Col1</div>
        <div class="col">Col2</div>
    </div>
```

**Some examples**

When using 2 `col` classes

[image]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      col - equal columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
       col - equal columns
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

When using `col-auto` for first column and `col` for second.

[image]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto">
      col-auto - hello
    </div>
    <div class="col">
       col - this column takes rest of available space
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Play here

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.container {
  width: 600px;
}

.row {
  padding: 10px;
}

.col,
.col-auto {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto">
      col-auto - hello
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      col - this column takes rest of available space
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there something similar for a whole table? I try to layout a table with bootstrap and would like the table to fit the column width to the longest cell in the column

Comment: @Qw3ry I did not get it clearly !! I suggest asking this as a new question, so that you will get more inputs.

Comment: Actually I wanted something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FN10HBEZOLVN) and I did not realize I could put another `row` inside of a `col`... 
But in my defense, I'm quite new to web programming, especially when it comes to frameworks like bootstrap^^

Answer (score 1):

Use `col-auto`. It will automatically take column size as per content size.

It will adjust width as per content in all devices.